# Keep current color when QTreeWidgetItem is selected

Tags: qt, qtreewidgetitem

I have a QTreeWidget with custom QTreeWidgetItem. At one point I change the color of an item but when the item is selected the color changes back to the old one.

I tried

```
pTreeItem->setTextColor(0, Qt::black);
```

and

```
pTreeItem->setForeground(0, Qt::black);
```

with the same results - the color changes when item is selected.

Is there a way to change this without using overriding paint?

Comment: Could you show us more code? (to reproduce this problem on our side) Now it is not clear what happens. And have you tried to use `setStyleSheet`/`setPalette` to fix this?

Comment: Use `QTreeView` + `QStandardItemModel` instead.

Comment: "True" MVC is not a case.
It is funny, but style sheets sometimes work better than "direct" colours handling.